# how to access sequential register based offset using uvm?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

i need to access 4 same register that are only different on offset.

reg layout:
reg0: 0x10
reg1: 0x14
reg2: 0x18
reg3: 0x20
and i use an autotool to generate uvm_block like following

```
class dut_reg_block extend uvm_reg_block
REG0 reg0;
REG1 reg1;
REG2 reg2;
REG3 reg3;
endclass;
```

support i have a function ConfigureDut(**RegNum**), and in it i want to access the register according **RegNum**(0~3), how to achieve this elegantly?

currently, code is something like this:

```
if (RegNum == 0) reg_block.reg0.read(data);
else if (RegNum == 1) reg_block.reg1.read(data);
else if (RegNum == 2) reg_block.reg2.read(data);
......
```

since the uvm_block is generated automatically, so i could not use array either.
can anyone suggest a better way to access these register?
thanks!

Comment: if registers are of the same type, or have the same base type, you can use an array of registers and select them by an index.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `read_reg_by_name` method:

```
reg_block.read_reg_by_name(status, $sformatf("reg%0d", RegNum), data);
```

You use `$sformatf` to build the register name as a string from the `RegNum` `int`:

```
$sformatf("reg%0d", RegNum)
```

and then take advantage of the fact that every component in UVM has a name and that name should be the same as the variable that references it.

Comment: amazing! thanks very much. never had a thought to use _read_reg_by_name._